# MVC 5 cshtml minification

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to minify Razor views (`.cshtml` files) on **compile-time**.

Currently, I use [WebMarkupMin](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin), but it minifies the HTML on **runtime**,

So, how can I minify `.cshtml` files on compile-time?

Comment: MVC cshtml files are compiled at runtime. You will probably need to look at another view engine or redefine the problem.

Comment: @Locke125 - I want to minify the Razor syntax (with the HTML, CSS, JS in the .cshtml file), not the HTML generated from the .cshtml file, it is a half minification, to improve the performance of the runtime minification (by the WebMarkupMin)

Comment: I assume you are trying to improve performance of something, but this may not be the most effective place to look for improvements. I don't use gulp, but you may be able to use it to do what you desire. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-cshtml You may also want to look at outputcache https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs You may want to define your goal in terms of a kind of performance gain rather than a specific feature because I think there may be easier ways to achieve it.

Comment: @Locke125 The cshtml files are by default compiled in runtime, but they're compiled only once when the view is first accessed. From that point on, the compiled code is cached, and they're not recompiled unless they change, or the web app restarts. Also, when you do a publish to a production environment, you can precompile the views to have a quicker startup time. That way the compilation of Razor happens in publish-time (build-time).

Answer (score 1):

I built a very trivial and easy to set up and easy to understand minifier for Razor and ASP.NET MVC 5. It just replaces multiple spaces with one, but that often has the biggest impact while having the least amount of side-effects.

Have a look if you're interested: https://github.com/tompazourek/RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5

---

Usually, it's recommended to use gzip encoding to minify HTTP responses, but I found out that if you minify the HTML before gzipping, you can still get around 11% smaller responses on average. In my opinion, it's still worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to minify your files at **anytime** (build-time) using the method outlined in this post: https://debugandrelease.blogspot.com/2018/11/automatically-minifying-cshtml-files-in.html

It makes use of a task runner to create minified `.cshtml` files. In development, you will work with the unminified versions of the files, but in higher environments, the minified `.cshtml` files will automatically be used. Please see the post for more details on how to set it up, or view the sample github sample repository linked at the end of the post.